# SQLITE + CHROME/SAFARI: "not authorized" ERROR

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, google-chrome, safari

I am trying to do a bulk transaction using SQLITE on CHROME (and SAFARI).

I'm doing this with javascript so this is what I have:

=============================================================

query = "BEGIN TRANSACTION; "

query += "INSERT INTO schools (name) VALUES('School 1');"

query += "COMMIT TRANSACTION;"

db.executeSql(query);

=============================================================

When I run this I get an error: NOT AUTHORIZED.

This only happens when I use the "BEGIN" or "BEGIN TRANSACTION" or "COMMIT" or "END TRANSACTION" keywords.

I've searched the web and the only thing that I can come up with so far is that the "NOT AUTHORIZED" error message means this functionality is not supported.

Does anyone know more about this?

Thanks,

Nik

Comment: I dont think you need "BEGIN TRANSACTION", "COMMIT", or end "END". Here is an example of Web SQL from webkit: http://webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you don't need the BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT and END keywords in your SQL queries.

I also have this error "not authorized (Code 1)" when I test my code with Safari in **private browsing mode** (menu Safari->Private Browsing). When turn off, it works perfectly.

DaveOnCode also [saw this behavior](http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/12/27/not-authorized-error-due-to-safari-private-browsing-mode/)